# Importance of well-pointedness (in particular for the pointed mapping cylinder construction)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

In a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169042/why-is-well-pointedness-necessary-for-x-hookrightarrow-m-f-to-be-a-pointed-cof), I asked wether well-pointedness was indeed necessary to make the canonical inclusion
$$X\hookrightarrow M_f^{\bullet}$$
a pointed cofibration. Here $X,Y$ are pointed topological spaces (compactly generated weak Hausdorff spaces to be precise), $f:X\to Y$ is a pointed map and $M_f^{\bullet}$ its pointed mapping cylinder. Unless I am deeply mistaken, the canonical inclusion is *always a pointed cofibration* (and the proof is virtually identical to the unpointed case), however, my main source on this material, Jeff Strom's *Modern Classical Homotopy Theory*, tells me that one should make the additional assumption of $Y$ being well-pointed, that is, the inclusion of the base point $\ast\hookrightarrow Y$ is an unpointed cofibration.

I could imagine well-pointedness of $Y$ being useful if we wanted to show $X\hookrightarrow M_f^{\bullet}$ to be an *unpointed* cofibration, although I couldn't show it actually is one. I've checked J.P. May's account on the subject in his *A concise Course in Algebraic Topology*, and well-pointedness doens't seem to play nearly as big a role as in Strom's book, at least May puts less emphasis on this condition.

> What's the deal with well-pointedness? Am I wrong about $X\hookrightarrow M_f^{\bullet}$ necessarily being a pointed cofibration? Why would I need well-pointed spaces, when in the pointed context I am only interested in extending pointed homotopies? Lastly, is it true that when $Y$ is well pointed, the canonical inclusion $X\hookrightarrow M_f^{\bullet}$ is an *unpointed* cofibration?

I am aware of a theorem that states that if $(\ast\in )A\rightarrow X$ is a pointed map and $A$ is well-pointed, then $A\rightarrow X$ is a pointed cofibration *iff* it is an unpointed cofibration. This seems like one important benefit of well-pointedness, but it doen't relate to my problem at hand.

**EDIT** @JustinYoung Thank you for your patience with this. I am not convinced by your counter example, here's why: the pointed mapping cylinder of the identity of $X$ should be homeomorphic to the countable union of closed segments with extremities $(1/n,0,0)$ and $(1/n,1/n,0)$ plus the origin as a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ (and also to $X\rtimes I$). Thus, $M^{\bullet}_{id}\rtimes I$ should be homeomorphic to the countable union of full squares with corners $(1/n,0,0),(1/n,1/n,0),(1/n,1/n,1/n),(1/n,0,1/n)$ plus the origin as a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ (and also to $(X\rtimes I)\rtimes I$). In this picture, $X\rtimes I\cup_X M_{id}^{\bullet}\rtimes\{0\}$ is all that has either $x=y$ or $z=0$. If you compress all these squares simultaneously onto their bottom right corner and sides, you get a strong deformation retraction of $M^{\bullet}_{id}\rtimes I$ onto $X\rtimes I\cup_X M_{id}^{\bullet}\rtimes\{0\}$. If you want I can can add my proof of the fact that the canonical inclusion $X\hookrightarrow M_f^{\bullet}$ is always a pointed cofibration, regardless of wether $Y$ is well pointed or not, and you can tell me if you agree or disagree. I can't to it tonight, but I might get to it tomorow.

Comment: As for the first question, let $X$ be the basepoint of $Y$ and let $f$ be the inclusion $X = * \to Y$. Then, the mapping cylinder $M_f = Y$ and the inclusion $X \to M_f$ is just the inclusion $X = * \to Y$. This is clearly a cofibration if and only if the base point is nondegenerate.

Comment: @JustinYoung Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure which question you answer though, what question is this an answer to?

Comment: The question is whether $X \to M_f$ is a pointed fibration, when $Y$ is not well pointed.

Comment: @JustinYoung I'm pretty sure it is a pointed cofibration regardless of wether $Y$ is well pointed or not: the definitions of Strom and May asks for the extendability of homotopies in the pointed category: during the whole process, the base point is always sent to the base point of the target space, so we don't need well pointedness of $Y$ as the base point is not allowed free roam.

Comment: Consider the example $X = \{0\}\cup \{1/n \mid n>0\}$, with basepoint $0$, and form the mapping cylinder of $id: X \to X$. Then, you can show that $X \to M_{id}$ is not a pointed cofibration by showing that $M_{id} \rtimes I$ does not retract onto $X\rtimes I \cup_X M_{id} \rtimes \{0\}$.

Comment: @JustinYoung Thanks for your comment, I couldn't fit mine in the comment space, so I added it as an edit to my original question.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat : Would you mind posting your proof here (if you remember it) or maybe say what your conclusion was? I am at the same problem as you now. I think that just showing that there are spaces such that $A \rightarrow A \vee B$ is not a pointed cofibration should do, no?

Comment: Or well, it wouldn't do, but it would be a start.

Comment: Hi @Dedalus, the fundamental question I had was why well-pointedness of $Y$ should play any role. Well-pointedness of $(Y,*)$ is a vacuous condition in the pointed setting, because base points must be preserved. To be precise, the base-point inclusion $*\to Y$ is always a pointed cofibration. For if you are given a map $f:Y\to Z$ and a based homotopy of $f_|{\lbrace *\rbrace}$ to extend to a homotopy on all of $Y$, you are actually given a map $f$ and the constant path at f(*)$. This has always an extension to $(Y,*)\wedge(I,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some thoughts towards an answer.

**Remark 1.** In Tammo tom Dieck's *Algebraic Topology*, Section 5.3 Problem 2 states what you want, namely that the inclusion $X \to M_f^{\bullet}$ of the "top" of the reduced mapping cylinder is a based cofibration. I'm not sure if tom Dieck has some mild point-set assumptions in the background.

**Remark 2.** A based map $i \colon A \to X$ is a based cofibration if and only if the "hat-shaped" map $$X \cup_A (A \wedge I_+) \to X \wedge I_+$$ admits a retraction. Here $$X \wedge I_+= X \times I / ({\ast} \times I) = X \rtimes I$$ denotes the reduced cylinder on $X$. That part of the argument is formal, like in the unbased case.

**Remark 3.** As a warm-up, we can focus on the case $f = \mathrm{id}_X$, as in your example above. In other words, is the inclusion $X \to X \wedge I_+$ of the "top" of the reduced cylinder a based cofibration?

If $X$ is exponentiable (i.e. the functor $X \wedge - \colon \mathrm{Top}_* \to \mathrm{Top}_*$ admits a right adjoint), then $X \to X \wedge I_+$ is a based cofibration. This follows from Remark 2 and the fact that the endpoint inclusion $\{ 1 \} \to I$ is a cofibration.

I don't see immediately if the answer is always yes, without assumption on the based space $X$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the category of compactly generated weak Hausdorff spaces, all objects are exponentiable, so I guess we are  in agrement.

Comment: That's right. If you're working in a convenient category of spaces $S$, then every space is exponentiable in the unbased sense (i.e., the functor $X \times - \colon S \to S$ has a right adjoint). It follows that every based (convenient) space is exponentiable in the based sense (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pointed+object#ClosedMonoidalStructure). Remark 3 then answers the question in the affirmative.

There still remains the question about naive topological spaces. I'm not sure if we need assumptions on the based space $X$ then.

Comment: More precisely, Remark 3 takes care of the case $f = \mathrm{id}_X$, and I think the argument can be adapted to any based map $f \colon X \to Y$.